# Netbeans Example App does not have main Method

Tags: netbeans

The code below was generated by netbeans. When I right click it there is an error that it does not have a main method. What should I do? It is on xubuntu using netbeans IDE 10 JDK 11 . I created the app using netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html. I right click HelloWorldApp.java and choose run. then I get the error .[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPfvH.png)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package helloworldapp;

/**
 *
 * @author peter
 */
public class HelloWorldApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

Comment: More information is needed. Update your question with the following: [1] The version of NetBeans. [2] Describe exactly what you did to generate that code. Give enough detail so that others can attempt to replicate your problem. [3] Add a screen shot showing the actual error.

Comment: Sorry, new to all this!  It is on xubuntu netbeans IDE 10.  I created the app using https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html.  I right click HelloWorldApp.java and choose run. then I get the error

Comment: OK, cool. But please click the edit button above, and directly update your question. Readers shouldn't need to read comments to get relevant information. And a screen shot of the error would definitely be helpful, as would your Java version.